# Is there a way to delete cache files on a per-project basis in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

Is there a way to delete cache files per-project in After Effects, instead of by date or by size of the cache?

Comment: Have you tried going to the cache folder and seeing if there's an identifiable projectfolder structure? I don't have an AE machine in front of me, so I can't check.